# Node.js failed to get data to the front-end page

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I'm trying to fetch the data from the database in the fetchData.js file. Then pass the the data in the script.js and feed the data into the chart. But the script.js just can't get the data from the fetchData.js and no error message is shown in the browser console. I have tested the file separately and either of them worked fine independently. But nothing showed up when script.js needs the data from the fetchData.js. I think something may be wrong with the url of the $.get in the script.js. I really don't know how to fix it. Please help...

script.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var options = {
            chart: {
                    renderTo: containerSpline,
                    type: 'spline'
                },
            title: {
                text: '信息录入统计曲线图'
            },
            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },
            xAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: '时间'
                },
                categories: []
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: '数量'
                }
            },
            series: []
    };

    $.get("/localhost:5050", (data)=>{
        // feed the data into the chart
        var series = {
            name:'', 
            data: []
            };
        var xAxis = {
                categories: []
            };
        data.recordset.forEach((item)=>{
            series.data.push(item.Count);
            series.name = item.Dates;
            options.xAxis.categories.push(item.Times);
        })
        options.series.push(series);
        var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options); 
    })
})
```

fetchData.js:

```
var express=require('express');
var http = require('http');
var sql=require('mssql');
var fs = require('fs');
var hbs = require('hbs');
var cors = require('cors');
var app=express();
var data;
//config for your database
var config={
        user:'***',
        password:'****',
        server:'***',   
        database:'****'
    };
    //connect to your database
sql.connect(config,function (err) {
  if(err) console.log(err);
    //create Request object
  var request=new sql.Request();
  var fDate, lDate;
  fDate = '2017-08-03';
  lDate = '2017-08-04';
  request.input('firstdate', sql.NVarChar, fDate);
  request.input('lastdate', sql.NVarChar, lDate);
  request.query(" EXEC dbo.KSD_Front_YbidCountByMinutes @firstdate , @lastdate ", (err,recordset) => {
                      if(err) console.log(err);
                    //send records as a response
                      data = JSON.stringify(recordset);
                    });
  });
// send the data to the script.js
app.use(cors());
app.get('/',function(req,res){
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type':'text/json;charset=utf-8'});
    res.end(data);
});

app.listen(5050,function(){
  console.log('Server is running!');
});
```

Comment: Your url should start with `//` not `/`.So `//localhost:5050`.  Hint: use the developpers console from your browser. Logging network traffic should have showed you it (probably, didn't test) tried to request `localhost:5050/localhost:5050`.

Comment: any errors in the browser console?

Comment: @Soronbe is right but I think that this may also be an `async` problem because reading of data is `async` and at the point of `app.get('/' ....` data may still be missing

Comment: @madalinivascu I test with chrome and firefox. Nothing shows up in the console

Comment: @codtex I changed it to //localhost:5050  still nothing shows up in the page and no error message in the browser console. So if this is an async problem, please tell me how can I fix it?

Comment: Make your server listen after it has the data (move it into the callback of the query). I don't really think this is the issue though, as the query should have been completed by the time it took you to manually switch to a browser and reload after a server restart.

Comment: @Soronbe You were right. It's not an async issue... After that, I used the browser sync to watch my front end part of the app and it all worked well, but I still don't know why... Sorry for such a late response.